# Laravel Zizaco/entrust using permission laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel

So i'm using Roles and Permissions Zizaco/entrust i came cross a problem i couldn't solve that when i use for example  `@role('admin') .. @endrole` it works no problem when i use `@permission('admin') .. @endpermission` it gives me this error

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cachedPermissions()

I tried alot of the internet answer none of them worked

.env file :

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=array
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you are confusing on `role` vs `permission`

Role is like `admin`, `guest` or `registered` ... I mean type of users

And permission is like `see-all-users`, `modify-profile` or  `cancel-report` ... I mean type of `Action` for which they have permission to act

So check once again what permissions you made or create new permission.

`roles` are not `permissions`

Make new permission like this

```
$editUser = new Permission();
$editUser->name         = 'edit-user';
$editUser->display_name = 'Edit Users'; // optional
// Allow a user to...
$editUser->description  = 'edit existing users'; // optional
$editUser->save();
```